# JavaScript: Why is my While-Loop Infinitely Looping?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I have a while loop that is an algorithm for a certain array path and I made it in javaScript. Here is the code.

```
var Row1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var Row2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var Row3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var Row4 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var Row5 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var AllRows = [];

//Add Rows
AllRows.push(Row1, Row2, Row3, Row4, Row5);
console.log(AllRows);

//First Value
var SV1 = [0, (AllRows.length - 1)];
var SV2 = [0, (AllRows.length - 1)];

var GetSV1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(SV1.length - 1));
var GetSV2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(SV2.length - 1));
AllRows[GetSV1][GetSV2] = 1;

var Steps = 1;
var PD = "false";
var RV1 = null;
var RV2 = null;
while(PD == "false"){
    RV1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(AllRows.length - 1));
    RV2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(AllRows.length - 1));
    if(AllRows[RV1][RV2] == AllRows[GetSV1][GetSV2] || AllRows[RV1][RV2] == "X"){
        continue;
    } else {
        AllRows[RV1][RV2] = 1;
    }

    if(AllRows[0][0] == 1){
        if(Steps >= 1 && AllRows[0][1] == 1){
            AllRows[1][0] = "X";
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 1 && AllRows[1][0] == 1){
            AllRows[0][1] = "X";
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else{
            AllRows[0][1] = 0;
            AllRows[1][0] = 0;
            AllRows[GetSV1][GetSV2] = 0;
        } 
        if(Steps >= 2 && AllRows[0][2] == 1){
            AllRows[1][1] = "X";
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 2 && AllRows[1][1] == 1){
            AllRows[0][2] = "X";
            AllRows[2][0] = "X";
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 2 && AllRows[2][0] == 1){
            AllRows[1][1] = "X";
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else{
            AllRows[0][2] = 0;
            AllRows[1][1] = 0;
            AllRows[2][0] = 0;
            AllRows[GetSV1][GetSV2] = 0;
        }
        if(Steps >= 3 && AllRows[0][3] == 1){
            AllRows[1][2] = "X";
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 3 && AllRows[1][2] == 1){
            AllRows[0][3] = "X";
            AllRows[2][1] = "X";
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 3 && AllRows[2][1] == 1){
            AllRows[3][0] = "X";
            AllRows[1][2] = "X";
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 3 && AllRows[3][0] == 1){
            AllRows[2][1] = "X";
            Steps++;
            continue;
        }  else{
            AllRows[0][3] = 0;
            AllRows[1][2] = 0;
            AllRows[2][1] = 0;
            AllRows[3][0] = 0;
            AllRows[GetSV1][GetSV2] = 0;
        }
        if(Steps >= 4 && AllRows[0][4] == 1){
            AllRows[1][3] = "X";
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 4 && AllRows[1][3] == 1){
            AllRows[0][4] = "X";
            AllRows[2][2] = "X";
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 4 && AllRows[2][2] == 1){
            AllRows[3][1] = "X";
            AllRows[1][3] = "X";
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 4 && AllRows[3][1] == 1){
            AllRows[2][2] = "X";
            AllRows[4][0] = "X";
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 4 && AllRows[4][0] == 1){
            AllRows[3][1] = "X";
            PD = null;
        } else{
            AllRows[0][4] = 0;
            AllRows[1][3] = 0;
            AllRows[2][2] = 0;
            AllRows[3][1] = 0;
            AllRows[4][0] = 0;
            AllRows[GetSV1][GetSV2] = 0;
        }
        if(Steps >= 5 && AllRows[1][4] == 1){
            AllRows[2][3] = "X";
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 5 && AllRows[2][3] == 1){
            AllRows[1][4] = "X";
            AllRows[3][2] = "X";
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 5 && AllRows[3][2] == 1){
            AllRows[4][1] = "X";
            AllRows[2][3] = "X";
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 5 && AllRows[4][1] == 1){
            AllRows[3][2] = "X";
            PD = null;
        } else{
            AllRows[1][4] = 0;
            AllRows[2][3] = 0;
            AllRows[3][2] = 0;
            AllRows[4][1] = 0;
            AllRows[GetSV1][GetSV2] = 0;
        }
        if(Steps >= 6 && AllRows[2][4] == 1){
            AllRows[3][3] = "X";
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 6 && AllRows[3][3] == 1){
            AllRows[2][4] = "X";
            AllRows[4][2] = "X";
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 6 && AllRows[4][2] == 1){
            AllRows[3][3] = "X";
            PD = null;
        } else{
            AllRows[2][4] = 0;
            AllRows[3][3] = 0;
            AllRows[4][2] = 0;
            AllRows[GetSV1][GetSV2] = 0;
        }
        if(Steps >= 7 && AllRows[3][4] == 1){
            AllRows[4][3] = "X";
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 7 && AllRows[4][3] == 1){
            AllRows[3][4] = "X";
            PD = null;
        } else if(Steps >= 7 && AllRows[4][4] == 1){
            PD = null;
        } else{
            AllRows[3][4] = 0;
            AllRows[4][3] = 0;
            AllRows[4][4] = 0;
            AllRows[GetSV1][GetSV2] = 0;
        }
    }else{
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Since I can't console out the problem, I can't find out what is causing this to infinitely loop but what I do know is it may have something to do with the declaration of RV1 and RV2. Can anyone tell me where in the code makes it loop forever?

**Update** I added my full code to help us further understand the problem.

Comment: The part that makes your code loop forever is `while(true)`. You should just step through this code using a debugger - you'll be able to follow along and see exactly why this loop never reaches your return.

Comment: A better question would be what *shouldn't* allow it to loop forever. I see 2 situations where you `return` rather than `continue`. What makes you think it should ever hit those lines? What could you do to guarantee that it will?

Comment: you may omit the `else` with using `return` or `continue`, because it ends the condition without ever going to the rest of the code/loop.

Comment: `while(true)`    
That might just have something to do with it.

Comment: @Chase  I took out the `while(true)`, but it still loops infinitely.

Comment: @MikeC Are yo suggesting that the probability it hitting those lines is slim-to-none?

Comment: Ignoring the ` if(AllRows[RV1][RV2] == AllRows[GetSV1][GetSV2]){
        continue;` because it's random numbers. However `else if(Steps >= 1){
            AllRows[0][1] = 0;
            AllRows[1][0] = 0;
            AllRows[GetSV1][GetSV2] = 0;
            continue;
        } ` will always continue, because steps is always greater or equal to 1

Comment: @TonyJ I realized this. I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: I can't seem to find where you declared AllRows and if I can't find its initial value, maybe JavaScript is having an issue, too b/c of that.

Comment: @slevy1 I declared it in the my full code, but I didn't put it in this code because I thought it would be unnecessary.

Comment: @BradleyWilliamEko It is necessary to include your data to test your code. Please provide some kind of data for AllRows.  Also, you have an illegal return statement in your while loop.  Note: you return from functions but you break from loops unless your loop is in a function and your code does not show the loop in a function.

Comment: @slevy1 I added the code that I have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points.  One, "false" does not equate with false nor with true because the string is a string value and true/false are boolean values. Although, you may write code like this:

```js
console.log(new Boolean("false") == true); // true
console.log("false" == String(true));      // false
```

See more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)

Don't have a mixed array with strings and numbers.  So, instead of "X", I use 99 but you can use whatever numeric value you deem fit.  You need to specify a condition to have the loop stop. Now the loop is no longer endless.  Also, see [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rYYMLX?editors=1112)

```js
var Row1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var Row2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var Row3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var Row4 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var Row5 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var AllRows = [];

//Add Rows
AllRows.push(Row1, Row2, Row3, Row4, Row5);
console.log(AllRows);

//First Value
var SV1 = [0, (AllRows.length - 1)];
var SV2 = [0, (AllRows.length - 1)];

var GetSV1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(SV1.length - 1));
var GetSV2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(SV2.length - 1));
AllRows[GetSV1][GetSV2] = 1;

var Steps = 1;
var PD = true; // "false" to true
var RV1 = null;
var RV2 = null;

while(PD === true){
    RV1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(AllRows.length - 1));
    RV2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(AllRows.length - 1));
    if(AllRows[RV1][RV2] == AllRows[GetSV1][GetSV2] || AllRows[RV1][RV2] == 99){
        continue;
    } else {
        AllRows[RV1][RV2] = 1;
    }

    if(AllRows[0][0] == 0){
        if(Steps >= 1 && AllRows[0][1] == 1){
            AllRows[1][0] = 99;
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 1 && AllRows[1][0] == 1){
            AllRows[0][1] = 99;
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else{
            AllRows[0][1] = 0;
            AllRows[1][0] = 0;
            AllRows[GetSV1][GetSV2] = 0;
        } 
        if(Steps >= 2 && AllRows[0][2] == 1){
            AllRows[1][1] = 99;
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 2 && AllRows[1][1] == 1){
            AllRows[0][2] = 99;
            AllRows[2][0] = 99;
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 2 && AllRows[2][0] == 1){
            AllRows[1][1] = 99;
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else{
            AllRows[0][2] = 0;
            AllRows[1][1] = 0;
            AllRows[2][0] = 0;
            AllRows[GetSV1][GetSV2] = 0;
        }
        if(Steps >= 3 && AllRows[0][3] == 1){
            AllRows[1][2] = 99;
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 3 && AllRows[1][2] == 1){
            AllRows[0][3] = 99;
            AllRows[2][1] = 99;
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 3 && AllRows[2][1] == 1){
            AllRows[3][0] = 99;
            AllRows[1][2] = 99;
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 3 && AllRows[3][0] == 1){
            AllRows[2][1] = 99;
            Steps++;
            continue;
        }  else{
            AllRows[0][3] = 0;
            AllRows[1][2] = 0;
            AllRows[2][1] = 0;
            AllRows[3][0] = 0;
            AllRows[GetSV1][GetSV2] = 0;
        }
        if(Steps >= 4 && AllRows[0][4] == 1){
            AllRows[1][3] = 99;
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 4 && AllRows[1][3] == 1){
            AllRows[0][4] = "X";
            AllRows[2][2] = "X";
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 4 && AllRows[2][2] == 1){
            AllRows[3][1] = "X";
            AllRows[1][3] = 99;
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 4 && AllRows[3][1] == 1){
            AllRows[2][2] = 99;
            AllRows[4][0] = "X";
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } 
      else 
        if(Steps >= 4 && AllRows[4][0] == 1){
            AllRows[3][1] = 99;
            PD = false;
        } else{
            AllRows[0][4] = 0;
            AllRows[1][3] = 0;
            AllRows[2][2] = 0;
            AllRows[3][1] = 0;
            AllRows[4][0] = 0;
            AllRows[GetSV1][GetSV2] = 0;
        }
        if(Steps >= 5 && AllRows[1][4] == 1){
            AllRows[2][3] = 99;
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 5 && AllRows[2][3] == 1){
            AllRows[1][4] = 99;
            AllRows[3][2] = 99;
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 5 && AllRows[3][2] == 1){
            AllRows[4][1] = 99;
            AllRows[2][3] = 99;
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else 
          if(Steps >= 5 && AllRows[4][1] == 1){
            AllRows[3][2] = 99;
            PD = false; //null to false
        } else{
            AllRows[1][4] = 0;
            AllRows[2][3] = 0;
            AllRows[3][2] = 0;
            AllRows[4][1] = 0;
            AllRows[GetSV1][GetSV2] = 0;
        }
        if(Steps >= 6 && AllRows[2][4] == 1){
            AllRows[3][3] = 99;
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 6 && AllRows[3][3] == 1){
            AllRows[2][4] = 99;
            AllRows[4][2] = 99;
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 6 && AllRows[4][2] == 1){
            AllRows[3][3] = 99;
            PD = false;
        } else{
            AllRows[2][4] = 0;
            AllRows[3][3] = 0;
            AllRows[4][2] = 0;
            AllRows[GetSV1][GetSV2] = 0;
        }
        if(Steps >= 7 && AllRows[3][4] == 1){
            AllRows[4][3] = 99;
            Steps++;
            continue;
        } else if(Steps >= 7 && AllRows[4][3] == 1){
            AllRows[3][4] = 99;
            PD = false;
        } else if(Steps >= 7 && AllRows[4][4] == 1){
            PD = false;
        } else{
            AllRows[3][4] = 0;
            AllRows[4][3] = 0;
            AllRows[4][4] = 0;
            AllRows[GetSV1][GetSV2] = 0;
        }
    }
     else{
        break;
    }
    
}
```

Note it is best to strictly compare Booleans with Booleans per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators). That is why this example uses the "===" operator for comparison and sets PD explicitly to true or false.